# How should I do to implement webrtc for native mobile

Tags: android, ios, webrtc

Now I just looking for any native library that helps me to implement webrtc with native mobile codes (Android Java, iOS Swift)

As I saw that libjingle have no updates around a year I does not sure that I still should use it, I don't want to use webrtc with third-party api such as Pubnub.

How about you guys suggestion or libjingle is good enough ?

Comment: Just some additional resources for WebRTC (that do not involve using PubNub - there are some helpful links in that article): https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-provide-webrtc-and-video-chat

Answer (score 0):

Sample are available in the official documentation. Refer https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

Answer (score 0):

libjingle has been "dead" since 2012, all relevant code moved over to https://webrtc.org which, unlike libjingle, has reasonably good instructions for checking out and building on mobile at https://webrtc.org/native-code/

Comment: In that page it said it is support only linux, I use windows so I try to find another document  I saw they are mention about libjingle peerconnection does not sure that I should use it or not

Answer (score 0):

Now the recommended way is to add the official library as dependency to your project.

implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'

You may refer the AppRTCMobile sample project which can be build by following the instructions given here - https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

There are sample projects on GitHub which have already done the hard work for you. I found [this one](https://github.com/duttaime/webrtcandroid) to be updated for Oreo.